# <If "-T env('HTTP_VAR_VAR')"> and <IfDefine HTTP_VAR_VAR> NOT working in Apache httpd-2.4.43-win64-VS16 + PHP 8

Tags: apache

this is Windows 10 + PHP 8 + Apache httpd-2.4.43-win64-VS16
(WAMP 2022)

my file **.htaccess** work 100% fine, when I add the line

```
php_value auto_prepend_file '/path/file.php'
```

into my **.htaccess** `file.php` is loaded and all work fine, 0errors, 0 warnings.

Now I need use a conditional into my **.htaccess**, then I put:

```
SetEnv HTTP_VAR_VAR1 'hello world1'
SetEnv HTTP_VAR_VAR2 'hello world2'
```

and result is 0 errors, the code PHP

```
var_dump(getenv('HTTP_VAR_VAR1'));
var_dump(getenv('HTTP_VAR_VAR2'));
```

return

```
string(12) "hello world1"
string(12) "hello world2"
```

yeah!, my **.htaccess** work fine

now I need evaluate the vars into my **.htaccess** and I add:

```
<If "-T env('HTTP_VAR_VAR1')">
php_value auto_prepend_file '/path/file1.php'
</If>

<IfDefine HTTP_VAR_VAR2>
php_value auto_prepend_file '/path/file2.php'
</IfDefine>
```

and NEVER auto_prepend_file is loaded

why

```
<If "-T env('HTTP_VAR_VAR')"> and <IfDefine HTTP_VAR_VAR>
```

not work ?

Answer (score 0):

from https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html

`The internal environment variables set by this directive are set after most early request processing directives are run, such as access control and URI-to-filename mapping. If the environment variable you're setting is meant as input into this early phase of processing such as the RewriteRule directive, you should instead set the environment variable with SetEnvIf.`

then I add the lines

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ".*USE_auto_prepend_file.*" HTTP_VAR_VAR3

<If "-T env('HTTP_VAR_VAR3')">
php_value auto_prepend_file '/path/file1.php'
</If>
```

into my **.htaccess** and code PHP from http://127.0.0.1/ONLY_THIS_DIR_USE_auto_prepend_file/file.php say:

```
string(1) "1"
```

but never **/path/file1.php** is loaded

only using directlly

```
php_value auto_prepend_file '/path/file.php'
```

the file is included

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html